# how to call ajax success and error function from controller?

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I have ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    type: "POST",  
    url: "",
    data: "", 
    success: function(){  
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    }       
});
```

& controller code is

```
public @ResponseBody
GenericResponse abc() {
    try {
        ....
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return new GenericResponse("Failed", ex.getMessage(), 500);
    }
    return new GenericResponse("Success", "", 200);
}
```

where GenericResponse is

```
public class GenericResponse 
{

    private String status;

    private String error;

    private int code;

    public GenericResponse(String s, String e, int c)
    {
        this.status = s;
        this.error = e;
        this.code = c;
    }
....
}
```

So for success & failure I am sending genericresponse with status but for both it goes inside success callback function. 
I understand that it is gennericResponse so ajax would consider it as success only . If exception comes 
I want it to go to error callback function. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning a GenericResponse, try returning a ResponseEntity instead.

You would do:

```
return new ResponseEntity<GenericResponse>(successGenericResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
```

or

```
return new ResponseEntity<GenericResponse>(failGenericResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```